# Get the value of a cell by row and column

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

```
CD_FARE MTH DAY ID_CALENDAR   H0    H1  H2  H3  PE1   PE2    PE3    PE4
2.0      1   M    Cal01       1     2   1   3   0.14  0.15   0.1    0.2 
2.0      1   T    Cal01       1     2   1   3   0.14  0.16   0.1    0.2
2.0      1   W    Cal01       1     2   4   3   0.14  0.12   0.1    0.2
2.0      1   T    Cal01       2     2   1   3   0.14  0.11*   0.1    0.2
2.0      1   F    Cal01       4     2   1   3   0.14  0.18   0.1    0.2
```

I want to know how can I get the value from a specific cell.

For example: I want to return the value 0.11. 
I know the position of the row (In this case 3), and the name of the column (PE2). 
Can I select the data in this way?:

```
data = df.iloc[3, 'PE2']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously it does not work, it gives a ValueError

```
ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types
```

But if you use `df.loc[3, 'PE2']` instead of the `iloc` method, it works

Answer (score 0):

If need select by position need [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
print (df['PE2'].iloc[3])
0.11
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'PE2':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6]}, index=['a','b','c'])

print (df)
   B  PE2
a  4    1
b  5    2
c  6    3

#third row in colum PE2
print (df['PE2'].iloc[2])
3

#index value c and column PE2
print (df.ix['c','PE2'])
3

#index value c and column PE2
print (df.loc['c','PE2'])
3

#third row and second column
print (df.iloc[2,1])
3
```

but if need select by index and column value use [`ix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) or [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'PE2':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6]})

print (df)
   B  PE2
0  4    1
1  5    2
2  6    3

print (df.loc[2, 'PE2'])
3

print (df.ix[2, 'PE2'])
3
```

You can also check [selection by label](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-label) and [selection by position](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position) in [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html).